# How Use url rerwiting or routing in VB to an dynamic query string

Tags: asp.net

How Can I use a simple easy way to make my URL shorten science the query string is a dynamic and its coming from the database

I have this www.example.com/details.aspx?Id=1&Type=Log
to be       www.example.com/1/log

Answer (score 0):

Here are two resources from MSDN to help you with routing. Next time, try googling something before asking a question.

[ASP.Net Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX)

[Routing Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)